# when user Each time navigate, should i do mysql query for checking JWT valid or not valid?

Tags: authentication, next.js, authorization, roles

I have a database with a table "users". it is a mysql database.
My question is, when an user is logged in. I store JWT token on database with a column named "isDestroyed"

If admin suddenly destroy the JWT token for a specific user, the user should not be able to navigate next page. it will redirect him to login page.

But how to implement it?
Because i am generating SESSION data with JWT token in SESSION and it is generated only once when user is logged in. Now each time the user is navigating, it is checking the SESSION data and ensuring whether it is OK or not.

Well,
Though SESSION data is OKAY. But what if the JWT token is destroyed or the USER account is completely deleted from the Database by the ADMIN of the website ? Then what will happen?

Since the user is navigating each protected page and it is checking the SESSION DATA only. Session data is available but the DATABASE data is deleted.

How will the client side know that the USER information is not available in the MYSQL DATABASE?

For that, should i create an api called

/api/me or /api/authorize

Whenever the user navigates, The middleware will do a fetch request and get the CURRENT USER INFO and also check whether the USER DATA is available or not or the JWT token is destroyed or not.

Once the check is passed, The user will be able to navigate to next page.

In this way, each time the user is navigating, we are making api call to that api url and it is making a mysql query to the database each time to check whether the USER DATA still available in DATABASE or not.

Is this a good practice to make mysql query on each protected page navigation?

because if i check the client side SESSION DATA or cookie data or local storage or whatever it is, Then the DATABASE check is not done. isnt it insecure?

Should we only depend on SESSION data or Implement the second approach of making an api call in the middleware to check?

I will be highly obliged if someone cordially explain this to me.

Thanks in advance

I have explained everything above. Please help someone :)